# HAProxy - Configure timeouts based on ACL

Tags: haproxy, timeout

I am using HaProxy for load balancing. I have multiple backeds, which are routed based on URLs.

In my haproxy.cfg file, I have setup the default

```
timeout client         1m
```

But, I want this value based on the ACL.i.e. for different ACL different values of timeout client.

I checked on the documentation and few blogs, but didn't find a way to achieve this.

Reference : http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#timeout%20server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible / supported. The client timeout value is set per frontend, not per request.

Answer (score 1):

What Florin said.

It also would not make much sense - if the client has not completed its request inside the timeout boundary, how is haproxy supposed to apply any ACL rule?

Comment: I was expecting like in front end.. HaProxy knows with ACL to use.. similary if we could set what client timeout to be used

Comment: Layer 4 ACLs may be evaluated before the request is complete, I'm not sure if this is done. I'm positive though that Layer 7 queries cannot be evaluated (there are e.g. no headers to compare yet). It would only make sense for HAproxy to defer ACL evaluation until the request is complete, which won't happen if the client timeout is reached first.